# Codenameone Form content with large list objects keep bouncing back to top of form

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to create a container with a sizable number ( > 20 or a number that exceeds the screen height) of items as a scrollable list using BoxLayout, it works (ie you can see the content moving up and down when one swipes) but trying to view items at the bottom of the list always results in the content pointer going back to the top of the list.  The expectation is scrolling down the list will lock the view to where the scroll action ended.  I also tried using TableLayout but the results are the same.  Any ideas? the mainform below also has the setScrollableY() set.

```
int rows = 30;
Form hi = new Form("Test",new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
hi.setScrollableY(true);

Container contents = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
contents.setScrollableY(true);

hi.add(contents);

for (int i = 0 ; i < rows;i++)
{
    Label type = new Label("ROW+"+i);
    type.setName(i+"");
    type.setTextPosition(Component.TOP);
    contents.addComponent(type);
}

mainform.addComponent(hi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
contents.setScrollableY(true);
```

You can only have one scrollable container in a hierarchy and you chose the `Form`. When you nest scrollables the gesture gets picked by one of them and it becomes an issue. Unlike the desktop where you can click on a specific scrollbar in a refined way, in touch devices you can't pick a specific container to scroll.